# liferay: how to first force logout in autologin hook

Tags: java, liferay

Apparantely liferay does not log the currently logged in user if you try to login again, and in fact even keeps the currently logged in user logged in.
So I'm trying to force a logout.

I tried:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

But that does not seem to work besides somehow breaking the login functionality.

I was wondering if anyone has any other idea how to force a logout.

Edit:

```
try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            EventsProcessorUtil.process(PropsKeys.LOGOUT_EVENTS_PRE,
                    PropsUtil.getArray(PropsKeys.LOGOUT_EVENTS_PRE), request, response);

            String domain = CookieKeys.getDomain(request);

            Cookie companyIdCookie = new Cookie(CookieKeys.COMPANY_ID,
                    StringPool.BLANK);

            if (Validator.isNotNull(domain)) {
                companyIdCookie.setDomain(domain);
            }

            companyIdCookie.setMaxAge(0);
            companyIdCookie.setPath(StringPool.SLASH);

            Cookie idCookie = new Cookie(CookieKeys.ID, StringPool.BLANK);

            if (Validator.isNotNull(domain)) {
                idCookie.setDomain(domain);
            }

            idCookie.setMaxAge(0);
            idCookie.setPath(StringPool.SLASH);

            Cookie passwordCookie = new Cookie(CookieKeys.PASSWORD,
                    StringPool.BLANK);

            if (Validator.isNotNull(domain)) {
                passwordCookie.setDomain(domain);
            }

            passwordCookie.setMaxAge(0);
            passwordCookie.setPath(StringPool.SLASH);

            CookieKeys.addCookie(request, response, companyIdCookie);
            CookieKeys.addCookie(request, response, idCookie);
            CookieKeys.addCookie(request, response, passwordCookie);

            try {
                session.invalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            EventsProcessorUtil.process(PropsKeys.LOGOUT_EVENTS_POST,
                    PropsUtil.getArray(PropsKeys.LOGOUT_EVENTS_POST), request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                PortalUtil.sendError(e, request, response);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServletException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Gives noclassdeffounderrors on cookiekeys/processorserviceutil/... depending on which I replace with a more base level. (like processorserviceutil with a processorserviceimpl and copy the function code from proeccesorserviceutil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) session.invalidate() only works if authentication is managed by the application server session, which it is not ;)

2) regardless of whether you use Community or Enterprise edition, you should have enough source code to achieve whatever you want

3) portal-ext.properties supports login chains as well as pre- and post-login hooks

4) Logout calls com.liferay.portal.action.LogoutAction which contains a bunch of logic but without spoiling the ending it should give you enough to shake the other Liferay authentication parts lose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going that route, but trying to use PropsValues gets me: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/util/PropsValues any idea why this happens? (I'm going for the hooks route)

Comment: PropsValues is packaged in the portal-impl and may require an ext project (assuming Liferay 6) but I'll need to check. If you're using LR6 and eclipse I strongly recommend using the Eclipse plugin available from help>market>search for liferay. The wizards are amazing.

Comment: I thought hooks had the same access as the ext plugins? And I used the liferay eclipse plugin to create the hook. This is why I'm confused since it did add a jar containing that class. (liferay 6.0.5)

Comment: and that would give you access to the class at compile time, but not necessarily at runtime, hence the runtime exception. There was considerable rewriting of the ClassLoader level in LR6 and while I have not done extensive work with all areas of the code, at times I have been forced to use ext plugins when I thought a hook should be sufficient.

Comment: Lovely, one of the requirements is that I don't use ext-plugins. And it really would be peeving to have to use an ext-plugin just to force a logout...

Comment: a better solution may be to add a custom AutoLogin implementation to the auto.login.hooks setting (see portal.properties) but I'm still seeing if it will work.

Comment: are we heading in the wrong direction? either a auto.login.hook or a pre-login hook should work, and if you don't use the PropsValue class and avoid the NoClassDefFoundError shouldn't that solve the initial problem?

Comment: I currently have a hook on the pre and on the login itself. However when using that code in the pre hook I get that exception. I'll update my startpost.

Comment: I haven't deployed the code I wrote, but it implements AutoLogin and steals the Cookie code from LogoutAction

Comment: The above code is copied from LogoutAction besides for the redirect parts which I removed.

Comment: take out the EventsProcessorUtil at the start and the end, but otherwise that's what I had. You can see that there is other work that needs to be done to expire cookies that retain authentication information hence session.invalidate() on its own is not enough.

Comment: I tried removing EventsProcessorUtil and I replacing it with: EventProcessor _private = new EventProcessorImpl(); _private.proces(...); and that line passes, but after that I also got an exception on cookieUtils, and I don't think rewriting the whole logoutaction to use other classes is a good idea.

Comment: I don't think you use the EventsProcessorUtil at all. Just delete it and try your code.

Comment: Then the CookieKeys gives a noclassdeffounderror. But either liferay really sucks at finding it owns classes or I'm having bad luck with my installs. Because I frequently have to relatively frequently reboot my liferay and redeploy to fix some noclassdeffounderrors for classes I know it can find.

Comment: In the interest of working towards a solution, try hardcoding those values. 6.0.5 is good but I have found problems too, and to be honest given the scope of the changes in version 6 I'd expect more to come for a while yet.

Comment: I will, I'll try it out this evening/tomorrow and give you a heads up. Thank you for your tips so far.